# postgresql - запрос

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL должен вернуть true или false. Не силен в синтаксисе SQL.

```
SELECT EXISTS
( 
    SELECT 1 FROM sec_user_role r
    WHERE r.user_id = :userId
        AND r.role_id = ? --тут нужно взять значение из запроса  select cast(json_extract_path_text(json_array_elements(:userRoles::json),'value') as integer) 
)
```

Как объеденить запрос?

Comment: `:userId` это не SQL. Заглушка-параметр? Замените такие на константы, для простоты :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте ещё один вложенный запрос:

```
SELECT EXISTS
( 
    SELECT 1 FROM sec_user_role r
    WHERE r.user_id = :userId
      AND r.role_id = (SELECT cast(json_extract_path_text(json_array_elements(:userRoles::json),'value') as integer)) 
)
```

Comment: Оператор `EXISTS` просто проверяет наличие строк соответствующих условию вы можете писать `SELECT  FROM` блок вывода не обязателен.